# Access localhost URLs with Java Spring and SSL

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc, ssl

I have to evaluate a JSP for further processing. It seems that there is no elegant solution for this. What I'm trying now to make is a workaround. I have a controller with request mappings that I use for the evaluation of JSPs. When accessing the URL with a `GET` I get the evaluated JSP as string. So I access the URLs on localhost.

Because of using SSL I have the problem with a `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` when I try to access the URL from the application. I don't want to import any certificates.

Is there a way to exclude selected URLs from SSL? Is there another way to access the URLs from "inside" the application like `mockMvc` with `get()` to bypass SSL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to exclude url's from your SSL configuration.

You can try something like this

```
 <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>appname</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>"Your exlusion Url pattern"</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

The transport guarantee type "None" makes it "unsecure" in a way.
I Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. The value in the `<url-pattern>` tag should not contain quotes -- simply `<url-pattern>/my-no-ssl-url*</url-pattern>`. This security constraint opens a no SSL HTTP port by Tomcat. If my application is accessible through `https://localhost:9443/` now I can access the no SSL URL through `http://localhost:8080/my-no-ssl-url`.

Comment: Yes ..I put the quotes just to show you that your url goes there.